# Delay in ALSA audio loopback how to resolve?

Tags: alsa

I am getting nearly 1 second delay in alsa audio capture and play loopback. While i checked there is no delay in capture, and for playback there is 1 second delay is coming.

Will you please tell me why the delay is coming and how can i resolve the problem.

Thanks,

Vijay Patil

Comment: Decrease the playback buffer size.

Comment: The buffer size is 3040